# Не выводятся данные mySql/Query/Ajax

Tags: php, sql, ajax

Помогите решить дилемму: пытаюсь вывести данные из БД по Ajax. Массив данных JSON формируется, однако данных на странице не вижу. Помогите найти косяк. Код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready (function previuLoad (){

        $.ajax ({

            type: "POST",
            url: "php/previuLoad.php",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data){

              $('#smenu').html(data);

            }                    
        });                
    });

</script>

<div id="smenu"></div>

<?php
    include 'db.php';

    mysql_query("set names 'utf8'"); 

    $result = array();

    $res = mysql_query ("SELECT title,link FROM foot", $db);    

    $arp = mysql_fetch_assos ($res);
    while ($arp = mysql_fetch_assos ($res)){
    $result[] = $arp
    }
    echo json_encode ($result);
?>
```

Массив в БД имеет вид: (id: 1.2.3.и.т.д.  title: title1. title2.title3 и.т.д.) и в таком духе.

У меня предположение, что я неправильно обращаюсь к многомерному массиву. Как должен выглядеть синтаксис запроса например третей записи Title:
data.2.title? Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: после `$result[] = $arp` не хватает точки с запятой.

Comment: Дилемма - это когда перед человеком есть несколько решений, каждое, которое спорно как правильный вариант, так как он упускает выгоду других вариантов. В вашем случае это просто задача). Насчет того в чем проблема, люди Вам уже ответили).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ошибка в этой строке. Что за `assos`? Надо:

   > `assoc ?  $arp = mysql_fetch_assos ($res);`
2. Выставь хедер перед строкой `echo json_encode ($result);` вот такой :

   > `header('Content-type: application/json');`
3. В JavaScript url: `"php/previuLoad.php"`. Это и есть запускаемый файл ?

Comment: В javascript url: "php/previuLoad.php", это и есть запускаемый файл ? , да, это запускаемый файл. по первому замечанию - банально опечатался. спасибо, попробую

Answer (score 1):

Видимо ошибка у тебя в том, что еще до выдачи Json твой скрипт вываливает HTML код. Либо переставь PHP-код выше HTML, либо измени dataType на "html" и уже тогда смотри на то, что возвращает сервер.

П.С. И давай уже ставь FireBug или пользуй DeveloperTools, дабы знать что приходит с сервера. А то у тебя скрипт ждет JSON, а что в реалиях приходит неизвестно.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить данные по Ajax нужно

1. УРЛ, посетив который, можно получить данные.
2. AJAX функция, которая обращается к этому УРЛ, желательно все-таки по протоколу GET, а не POST.

Данные вообще с сервера отдаются?

Comment: сам по себе скрипт (запускаю из строки напрямую) json массив формирует. приходит ли он скрипту - хз, firebug ошибку не показывает. Типы данных пробовал разные, последовательности тоже. Вывод без Json_encode просто в цикле (данные HTML) возвращает хз какие кракозябры.

Comment: Если открыть этот УРЛ в браузере, что-нибудь отобразится на странице?

Answer (score 0):

Огромное спасибо ActivX!! Проблема была в Php скрипте.
правильный Вариант:

```
<?php
include 'db.php';

mysql_query("set names 'utf8'"); 

$result = array();
$i = 0;

$res = mysql_query ("SELECT id,title,link FROM foot", $db);    

$arp = mysql_fetch_assoc ($res);

do{
$result[$i] = $arp;
$i++;
}
while ($arp = mysql_fetch_assoc ($res));
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode ($result);
```

?>

Всем отозвавшимся спасибо!!!